# Transaction check error when install mysql 8.0.13

Tags: mysql, centos7

I install mysql on Centos 7 by command

```
yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm
```

After that:

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

And this is error after process run:

```
Downloading packages:
(1/7): libaio-0.3.109-13.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                       |  24 kB  00:00:00
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/mysql80-community/packages/mysql-community-common-8.0.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
Public key for mysql-community-common-8.0.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(2/7): mysql-community-common-8.0.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                         | 554 kB  00:00:00
(3/7): mysql-community-libs-8.0.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                           | 2.3 MB  00:00:00
(4/7): mysql-community-client-8.0.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                         |  26 MB  00:00:01
(5/7): numactl-libs-2.0.9-7.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                    |  29 kB  00:00:00
(6/7): Percona-Server-shared-56-5.6.36-rel82.1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                 | 619 kB  00:00:02
(7/7): mysql-community-server-8.0.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                         | 381 MB  00:00:11
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                 34 MB/s | 410 MB  00:00:11
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
Importing GPG key 0x5072E1F5:
 Userid     : "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>"
 Fingerprint: a4a9 4068 76fc bd3c 4567 70c8 8c71 8d3b 5072 e1f5
 Package    : mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch (installed)
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /etc/my.cnf conflicts between attempted installs of Percona-Server-shared-56-5.6.36-rel82.1.el7.x86_64 and mysql-community-server-8.0.13-1.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Please, help me solve the problem, i searched on many pages but still not have the solution

Solved: i tried `yum remove Percona*;`
and reinstall mysql, it worked. But not sure any problem next. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you have percona server installed on your system.

```
yum list installed | grep -i percona
```

You can use repoquery with the '--file' flag so that you can see what package the file belongs to:

```
repoquery --file /usr/bin/mysql
```

Try uninstalling percona server and then try reinstalling mysql.

Comment: Not yet try your solution, but before read your reply, i tried to remove Percona-Server-shared and reinstall mysql success. Thks you so much